# Неправильная работа ActionBar?

Tags: android

Всем привет! У меня почему то начал глючить ActionBar. Не показывает ни иконку, ни меню. Просто пусто.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в манифесте прописана иконка и даже андройд студио показывает иконку.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" >
```

Вот мой стиль

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>



    </style>
```

Хотел уже вручную поставить иконку через getActionBar().setIcon(); но он выдает null. Т.е. не может найти Action Bar. Что делать ребят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перед методом `getSupportActionBar.setIcon();` вызывай метод `getSupportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: Спасибо подсказали верно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `getSupportActionBar()`. Если не поможет - покажите Activity.